# Python Requests Get(URL) 200 response, no data

Tags: python, python-2.7, api

I am using the request library to do a GET request. I can get a 200 response but it returns no data, it returns the object 'jobs' but then nothing else. I am using the Visualping.io api. I have successfully run CURl commands, and Success from browser url.... Here is my python code. I have edited out my credentials and PHP sesh id.

```
`import requests
r = requests.get("https://visualping.io/api/job/list", headers={'username':'myemail@email.com', 'password':'MyPassword', 'User-Agent':'test'})
print (r.content)
print (r.status_code)
print (r.headers)
print (r.json)`
```

I have also tried without the user and pass as headers, and just passed them in the url like this.. Again this works from a browser and curl

```
`https://visualping.io/api/job/list?username='myusername'&password='mypassword'`
```

For both of these, I get the following output

//printcontent {"success":true,"jobs":[]}

//Print status code 200

//Below is print headers

{'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.5.35', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID={MYSESSIONID}; expires=Fri, 26-May-2017 20:42:31 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Date': 'Fri, 26 May 2017 19:42:31 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}

//This is print json
{u'jobs': [], u'success': True}

Here it is in one block

```
`{"success":true,"jobs":[]}
200
{'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.5.35', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID={MYSESSIONID}; expires=Fri, 26-May-2017 20:43:47 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Date': 'Fri, 26 May 2017 19:43:47 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>`
```

https://company-32327.frontify.com/d/Lr7wNKb1omxI/visualping-api

Here is an expected response from the documentation
GET /api/job/list

```
`{
    "jobs": {
        "active": [
          {
            "id": "NzqkVe1AI6WYBli",
            "created": "2015-09-06 00:37:16",
            "url": "www.google.de",
            "description": "Google Landing Page",
            "runs": "10",
            "trigger": "1",
            "interval": "60",
          }  
        ],
        "inactive": [
          {
            "id": "gCXHiydaCulFOFA",
            "created": "2016-09-06 00:37:16",
            "url": "www.bing.de",
            "description": "Bing Landing Page",
            "runs": "25",
            "trigger": "10",
            "interval": "300"
          }  
        ],
    }
}`
```

Comment: Update: passing no credentials yields the same result"success":true,"jobs":[]}
200
{'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.5.35', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=9aq0m56d1otm617hoidnl40np4; expires=Fri, 26-May-2017 21:12:55 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Date': 'Fri, 26 May 2017 20:12:55 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json` is a function, please try this one:

```
print(r.json())
```

So, you're just missing parentheses. You're accessing a method as you can see in your output:

```
<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
```

Answer (score 4):

The docs you linked to for VisualPings api say they only support HTTP Basic Auth so try:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
r = requests.get("https://visualping.io/api/job/list", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('myusername', 'mypassword'))
print(r.json())
```

[Requests Basic Auth docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)